# NoMethodError (undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In controller:

```
def createUserForHotel
  @user=User.new(params_createUserForHotel)
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice]="New user is created for the hotel"
    redirect_to(:controller=>'hotels',:action=>"createnewhotel")
  else
    flash[:notice]="New user not created "
    redirect_to(:controller=>'hotels',:action=>"createnewhotel")
  end
end

def params_createUserForHotel
  params.require(:user).permit(:username,:password,:email,:hotel_id)
end
```

In migration:

```
def up
  create_table :users do |t|
    t.string "first_name",:limit=>25
    t.string "last_name",:limit=>50
    t.string "email",:null=>false,:limit=>100
    t.string "username",:limit=>50  
    t.string "password",:limit=>40 
    t.integer "hotel_id"
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index("users","hotel_id")
end

class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up          
    rename_column("users","password","hashed_password")   
  end
```

In Heroku logs:

```
←[0m Started POST "/hotels/createUserForHotel" for 122.50.216.93 at 2014-11-16 10:18:16 +0000
←[36m2014-11-16T10:18:16.170638+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-11-16T10:18:16.170641+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m NoMethodError (undefined method password_digest=' for #<User:0x007f036c8ffe50>):
←[36m2014-11-16T10:18:16.170643+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/hotels_controller.rb:140:in createUserForHotel'
←[36m2014-11-16T10:18:16.170644+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

My application is working perfectly in development environment, but i am getting the above error in Heroku logs.I have deployed my application in Heroku.

Comment: Please next time be gentle and spend some time to learn how to properly indent and format your code.

Comment: Make sure you have `bcrypt` gem and also in your user mode you have to type `has_secure_password`

Answer (score 5):

Your `password` column should be named `password_digest` - not `hashed_password` or `password`

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are not automatically executed on deploys. Make sure to run `rake db:migrate` on Heroku.

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

See this [Rails 4 on Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#migrate-your-database).

Comment: I know, i have completed the whole migration process on Heroku.I found that bcrypt (3.1.9) is present in heroku, where as in my gemfile "gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'" is there.Is this causes error?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can delegate (or stub)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def password_digest=(hashed_psw)
    hashed_password = hashed_psw
  end
end
```

P.S. It will be better if you create column `password_digest`

Comment: This setter does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias_attribute :password_digest, :password_column_name` in your **User** model